# How to Use Data Inside Var in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to sum records using Group by from the all data inside "result view".

[image]

can anyone guide me for this.!

Here is My Code

```
var tData1 = (from i in _data.Transactions
                          join y in _data.DeviceInformations on i.DeviceInfoId equals y.DeviceInfoId
                          join u in _data.AccountDevices on y.DeviceInfoId equals u.DeviceInfoId
                          where y.Active == true && u.AccountId == 1000001 && u.Active == true
                          group i by i.DeviceInfoId into g
                          select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateCreated)).ToList();


foreach (var xCo in tData1)
{
   //I am getting Data in xCo
}
```

Comment: Can you please write your code which you used..

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Nayeem Mansoori solution you can try this.

```
var tData1 = (from i in _data.Transactions
                          join y in _data.DeviceInformations on i.DeviceInfoId equals y.DeviceInfoId
                          join u in _data.AccountDevices on y.DeviceInfoId equals u.DeviceInfoId
                          where y.Active == true && u.AccountId == 1000001 && u.Active == true
                          group i by i.DeviceInfoId into g
                          select new {Id = DeviceInfoId, sum = g.Sum(x=>x.DeviceInfoId)};
```

Comment: Thanks Ish, I also want to do group by with sum and it's giving me error to use both things together.

Comment: Didn't get why you want to perform group by on sum. As sum returns you one value.

Comment: Or i didn't get you question properly. Can you further elaborate it.?

Comment: From above code i am fetching the data of the DeviceInfoId using group by and it giving me the result that you can see in the image, Now i want to again Sum of the Particular ids using Group by inside the Result that i am getting from above code or you can see into the result it had 10 rows.

Comment: i break the query and got the result which i want thanks to all.. :)